# How do I submit a node form?

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

How can I set up a node form to submit via AJAX?

I can't find examples that show how to do this explicitly. I am trying to run AJAX submission in a popup window.

After adding `use-ajax-submit`, the request starts correctly, but after saving the node it redirects to the node page and everything crashes.

Comment: Example in a block: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/236624/edit-a-node-using-ajax

Comment: @rémy Thank you! I think class "use-ajax-submit" will help.

Comment: @rémy question was updated